# Reading a range of MS Project tasks

Tags: ms-project

Using VBA, is there a way to read a particular property of a range of tasks from MS Project without looping. This is much like reading a range or named range of cells with one statement in VBA for Excel. So instead of looping through say all the tasks in a given Project file perhaps a statement like

DIM datStart() as Date

datStart=activeproject.tasks.start.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Project object model does not support reading values from multiple tasks at once. However, looping through tasks is very fast and simple.

```
Sub GetStarts()

    Dim numTasks As Long
    numTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks.Count

    Dim datStart() As Date
    ReDim datStart(numTasks)
    
    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To numTasks
        datStart(idx - 1) = ActiveProject.Tasks(idx).Start
    Next idx

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok good to know Rachel. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to do something like this I first create a filter to isolate the tasks using the FilterEdit Method. Then I use SelectAll and loop through ActiveSelection.Tasks